# I'm trying to parse a JSON file and save the data to be attributes of a custom object I made

Tags: python, json, object

I'm trying to make a python file that reads this huge movie database

```
https://github.com/prust/wikipedia-movie-data
```

I made a custom class called movie that takes a title, genre, director, and an array of actors as parameters. Right now I have the JSON file loaded and I can display all the data, but I want to just save these specific parameters (all of which are present) into movie objects that will be stored in an array/list or something.

Here's my code for my tester class:

```
from movie import Movie
from user import User
import json
from pprint import pprint


movieArray = []

with open('movies.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    print(d)

##json_movie_data = json.dumps(json_data)

for x in d['results']:
    print ['title'][x]

movieToBeInputted = Movie("","","","","")

##movieToBeInputted.actors = json_movie_data
for aMovie in d:
   # print(aMovie.title)
    movieArray.append(aMovie)


for i in movieArray:
    print(i)

starWars = Movie("A new hope", "2", ["3", "2"], "5", "6")

print(starWars.name)
```

Here's my code for my movie class:

```
class Movie:

    def __init__ (self, name, genre, actors, director, inSequal):
       self.name = name
       self.genre = genre
       self.actors = []
       self.director = director
       self.inSequal = inSequal




movieA = Movie("star wars", "eh", [], "eh", "eh" )


movieA.actors.append("Dumbo")
print(movieA.name)
print(movieA.actors[0])
```

Here's how the JSON file is formatted:

```
    [
  // ...
  {
    "title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron",
    "year": 2015,
    "director": "Joss Whedon",
    "cast": "Robert Downey, Jr., Chris Evans, Chris Hemsworth, Mark Ruffalo",
    "genre": "Action",
    "notes": "Walt Disney, Sequel to The Avengers (2012), Based on the comics of the same name by Stan Lee and Jack Kirby"
  },
  // ...
  {
    "title": "Avengers, The Avengers",
    "year": 2012,
    "director": "Joss Whedon",
    "cast": "Robert Downey, Jr., Chris Evans, Mark Ruffalo, Chris Hemsworth, Scarlett Johansson, Jeremy Renner, Tom Hiddleston, Clark Gregg, Cobie Smulders, Stellan Skarsgård, Samuel L. Jackson",
    "genre": "Superhero",
    "notes": "Walt Disney Pictures, Marvel Studios, Based on the comic book of the same name by Stan Lee and Jack Kirby"
  }
  // ...
]
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Show the error/describe the problem. Preferably add the wanted output.

Comment: The problem is I'm only able to print out the entire json file, but I want to instead save certain attributes to variables.

Comment: What you want to save, what is expected output?

Comment: I'd like to save title, actors, genre, and director.